# mypy declares IO[bytes] incompatible with BinaryIO

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Consider the following code:

```
from io      import TextIOWrapper
from typing  import List
from zipfile import ZipFile

def read_zip_lines(zippath: str, filename: str) -> List[str]:
    with ZipFile(zippath) as zf:
        with zf.open(filename) as bfp:
            with TextIOWrapper(bfp, 'utf-8') as fp:
                return fp.readlines()
```

Running mypy v0.782 on the above code under Python 3.6.9 fails with the following error:

```
zfopen.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "TextIOWrapper" has incompatible type "IO[bytes]"; expected "BinaryIO"
```

However, I feel that this code should not be regarded as an error, as `ZipFile.open()` returns a binary filehandle, which `TextIOWrapper` accepts.  Moreover, `IO[bytes]` and `BinaryIO` are (as far as I understand) effectively the same thing; it's just that `BinaryIO` is declared as a subclass of `IO[bytes]`.  I would naïvely expect `IO[bytes]` to be accepted everywhere that `BinaryIO` is, except that's not how subclasses work, and I'm not sure how to properly make use of this subclassing when typing.

Who is in error here, and how does the error get fixed?

- Is typeshed in error for declaring the return type of `ZipFile.open()` as `IO[bytes]` instead of `BinaryIO`?
- Is typeshed in error for declaring the type of the first argument to `TextIOWrapper` as `BinaryIO` instead of `IO[bytes]`?
- Is the `typing` module in error for making `BinaryIO` a subclass of `IO[bytes]` instead of an alias?
- Is my code in error for not performing some sort of cast on `bfp`?
- Is my thinking in error for expecting `bfp` to be passable to `TextIOWrapper` unmodified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shorter test case with mypy 0.782 gets the same error:

```py
    binary_file = io.open('foo.bin', 'rb')
    text_file = io.TextIOWrapper(binary_file, encoding='utf-8', newline='')
```

whether `binary_file` is explicitly declared as `IO[bytes]` or inferred.

**Fix:** Use `mypy 0.770` or `mypy 0.790`.

It was a regression in mypy's typeshed ([Issue 4349](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/4349)) and the fix is in mypy 0.790, fixing both `zipfile.open()` and `io.open()`.